# Is there a way to setFocus in Captivate 9

Tags: adobe-captivate

I have a Next button at the bottom of the page. When I click the Next button, using VoiceOver or TalkBack, it goes to the Next button on the new page. Is there a way to set focus to the top of the page with Captivate 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a transparent button at the top of the page and set its tabbing order to be 1.